# Flux Through Sperical Cap

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

So I have the spherical Cap formed by the interception of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and the plane $z=1$. Given the field $\vec{F}=(xy^2z,yz^3,y^4)$, I want to calculate the flux *through the cap*:

$$
\iint_{S}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS
$$

I already know that $\vec{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(x,y,z)$, so, evaluated at the surface in question:

$$
\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}zy^2
$$

By deffinition we have $\vec{n}=\frac{\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v}{||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||}$. So as far as I understand, I can write $||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||=\sqrt{5}$.

This last bit allows me to write $dS=||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||dA=\sqrt{5}dA$.

Now I have 2 options: Either I work in sperical coordinates, or cilyndrical. As it turns out I have a problem with both.

**For spherical coordinates** I end up with an answer that is $20\sqrt{5}\pi$ where the answer is actuall $20 \pi$. This indicates to me that probably my reasoning about the part "$||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||=\sqrt{5}$" is wrong.

**For cilyndrical coordinates** I used

$$
x=r\cos(\theta) \qquad y=r\sin(\theta)  \qquad z=\sqrt{5-r^2} 
$$

with $r\in [0,2]$ because of the "domain" of the region. And $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Unfortunately the asnwer doesn't match either.

I would appreciate any kind of indication of where things went wrong and/or sugestions of how to make things right!

Comment: First, to use your approach you would need to calculate $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}$ when $\vec{n}$ is normal to the cap and when $\vec{n}$ is normal to the plane (pointing directly downward) and then add together. Second, it looks like your computation of $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}$ is wrong, as $$(xy^{2}z,z^{3},y^{3}) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (x^{2}y^{2}z + yz^{3} + y^{3}z) \ne \sqrt{5} zy^{2}$$ Finally, why not just use the divergence theorem?

Comment: Notice $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(x^2y^2z +yz^3 +y^3z)=\frac{zy^2}{\sqrt{5}}(x^2 +z^2 +y^2)$$ but at the surface, we have $$x^2 +z^2 +y^2=5$$, which gives my result. I didn't want to use the divergence theorem because I didn't want to "close" my region.

Comment: Also, maybe I wasn't clear. The region I am interested in is only the cap of the sphere

Comment: The idea is you add and substract the close of the region. You divergence over the volume, and you surface over the flat area

Comment: Check your factorisation again.

Comment: I had written the field F incorrectly. My calculations were according to the correct field. I apologize